# Конвертирование видео средствами php и ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Не нашел даже похожего поисковиком. Нужно после загрузки файла во временную папку перекодировать его ffmpeg'ом после чего оно автоматом должно записать в бд успешную конвертацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
 // Задаем источник и путь к будущему результату
 $srcFile = "/path/to/clock.avi";
 $destFile = "/path/to/clock.flv";
 $ffmpegPath = "/path/to/ffmpeg";
 $flvtool2Path = "/path/to/flvtool2";
 // Создаем объект класса ffmpeg
 $ffmpegObj = new ffmpeg_movie($srcFile);
 // Записываем необходимые параметры отображения
 $srcWidth = makeMultipleTwo($ffmpegObj->getFrameWidth());
 $srcHeight = makeMultipleTwo($ffmpegObj->getFrameHeight());
 $srcFPS = $ffmpegObj->getFrameRate();
 $srcAB = intval($ffmpegObj->getAudioBitRate()/1000);
 $srcAR = $ffmpegObj->getAudioSampleRate();
 // Запускаем конвертацию из командной строки, используя exec()
 exec($ffmpegPath . " -i " . $srcFile . " -ar " . $srcAR . " -ab " . $srcAB . " -f flv -s " . $srcWidth . "x" . $srcHeight . " " . $destFile . " | " . $flvtool2Path . " -U stdin " . $destFile);
 // Функции умножителя
 function makeMultipleTwo ($value)
 {
 $sType = gettype($value/2);
 if($sType == "integer")
 {
 return $value;
 } else {
 return ($value-1);
 }
 }
 ?>
```

первая же ссылка в гугле по запросу ***ffmpeg php convert video***
Вольный перевод. =)

Comment: Вот спасибо то выручили) А я все конвертация конвертация искал)